# Sliding the Latest News or Updates in the First Page of the Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am beginner in a web development and I am working in my senior project which is a web-based system and I want to show the visitors of my website the latest news or updates in the homepage. I want to display them in a dynamic way such as those JQuery sliding images. I tried to display them using the nice images slider from the following website: http://slidesjs.com/

but I failed because its width is big (it is more than 700px) and I tried to play with it using firebug plugin in Firefox and change some numbers in CSS file but I could not be able to make it suitable for my website

I heard there are some JQuery templates for that. I tried to search about them but I did not get anything. I want something with width 700px or less and it can be modified easily.

So could you please help me in this issue? Please provide me with any guide that is helpful to do this issue. Also, please provide me with your suggestions for presenting the latest news in the website?

Comment: Should we really be helping you with your homework? ;) I suppose we help each other with our work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the width in the css for that slider

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .slides_container {
    width:470px;
    height:170px;
  }
  .slides_container div {
    width:470px;
    height:170px;
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

If you change those values it should be fine!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
Actually, I did that before and my problem with it in how saving the same style of sliding images.

Can I send you what I did through your email? so you can get a good look at it